# Неверный результат при делении

Tags: ассемблер

Произвожу деление и вывод остатка в консоль(x86 NASM,Linux):

```
section .data                            

dividend dd 50
divider dd 11;

msg dd 'Title'
lenMsg equ $- msg

 section .bss
reminder resb 4


section .text          
 global _start

_start: 

;Show text
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, msg
mov edx, lenMsg
int 80h 
;end Show text



mov eax,[dividend]
mov ebx,[divider]
div ebx


mov ebx,edx
add ebx,'0'
mov [reminder],ebx

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, reminder
mov edx, 4
int 80h 

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 80h
```

Результат выполнения 5(хотя должно быть 6). Если убираю блок "Show text"(помечен коментарием), то все работает нормально. Подскажите в чем причина ошибки? И каким образом блок вывода текста меняет результат?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Команда `div` делит не `eax` на `ebx`, а `edx:eax` (quad word, 64 бита) на `ebx` ([дока](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html#section-A.25)).

Если убрать показ текста то перед делением в `edx` будет лежать 0. Для показа текста вы изменяете edx, но не обнуляете после показа, из-за этого меняется результат деления.

Для того чтобы код работал как ожидается нужно перед делением выставлять edx в 0.